# How to trigger destroy child on change of the relationship to a different record in the child table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We have a parent child relationship that is one:one where

parent.child_id = child.id

It's likely and possible that the parent.child_id can be changed to a different child_id. without deleting the parent. How can we automatically destroy/delete the child record that has become orphaned by this action?

our models look like this:
parent

```
class parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child, dependent: :destroy

  after_commit :destroy_orphans, on: [:create, :update]

  def destroy_orphans
    Child.where.not(id: Parent.all.pluck(:child_id)).destroy_all
  end
end
```

We've added the destroy_orphans method as such to accomplish this, but it's adding query overhead that probably doesn't need to exist.

child

```
class child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :parent, inverse_of: :child, dependent: :nullify

  before_save { build_parent unless parent && !parent&.child_id.nil? }
end
```

what we would like is to trigger deletion/destroy of the child if the child_id changes on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of the previous_changes option (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/previous_changes) available in the Rails active record to achieve this. We can get the previous child of the parent and delete the child. Try the below,

```
    class parent < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :child, dependent: :destroy

      after_commit :destroy_orphans, on: [:create, :update], if: -> { previous_changes['child_id'].present? }

      def destroy_orphans
       previous_child = Child.find_by(id: previous_changes['child_id'].first)
       previous_child.destroy unless previous_child.parent.present?
      end
    end
```